# return 2d array from function in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function declared like so:

```
unsigned char** Classifier::classify(){
      //...
    unsigned char **chars = new unsigned char *[H];
for(int i = 0; i < H; i++)
    chars[i] = new unsigned char[W*3];

//...

return &chars;
//note: when this is "return chars;" I get the following:  cannot convert ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘unsigned char**’ in return
```

This is giving me the warning:

```
Classifier.cpp: In member function ‘unsigned char** Classifier::classify()’:
Classifier.cpp:124: warning: address of local variable ‘chars’ returned
```

Is this ok to ignore? Basically, my question is how do you return a reference to an array that is defined in the function?

I want to be able to do

```
unsigned char** someData = classify();
```

Comment: Don't use raw arrays if you don't have to. Use std::vector instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **never** okay to ignore. You're returning the address of a local variable. That address will become invalid when you leave `classify()`'s stack frame, *before* the caller has a chance to use it.

You only need to return the value of that variable instead:

```
return chars;
```

Comment: so if I take away the &, I get  cannot convert ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘unsigned char**’ in return

Comment: That would mean you declared `chars` as an `unsigned char *`, not an `unsigned char **` as in your code above.

Comment: ack..you're right - i forgot to include some flags to compiler a different section of code! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Just return the array, not its address:

```
return chars;
```

`&chars` is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer, but `chars` is a pointer to a pointer (what you want).  Also note that `chars` is *not* an array.  Pointers and arrays are not the same thing, although they are often confused.

Comment: I tried this at first, but when I took away the addressof I get this:  cannot convert ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘unsigned char**’ in return

Comment: @Derek: Try it: show me code that says exactly `return chars;` and that gives that error message.

Answer (score 3):

@Adam Rosenfield has got the correct answer and so have some others, (remove that ampersand) but as food for thought, a nice way to do this is to use a std::vector (of std::vectors) and pass it into the function as a reference parameter.

```
#include <vector>

void Classifier::classify(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> & chars)
{
      //construct a vector of W*3 integers with value 0
      //NB ( this gets destroyed when it goes out of scope )
      std::vector<unsigned char> v(W*3,0);

      //push a copy of this vector to the one you passed in - H times.
      for(int i = 0; i < H; i++)
         chars.push_back(v);
}
```

`chars` is populated with the stuff you want and when it comes to deleting the `vector`, you don't have to worry about how to call the correct `delete[]` syntax that you would with those two calls to `new` in your 2D array.

You can still reference items in this vector as you would with your 2D array e.g. `chars[5][2]` or whatever.

although I can see you want to be able to go:

```
 unsigned char** someData = classify();
```

So if you wanted to use vectors, you'd have to declare someData as follows:

```
 std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> someData;
```

and to make that clearer perhaps:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> vector2D;
vector2D someData;
classify(someData);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If an array defined in function and if you want to use it outside the function - you should describe it (array) as static or declare an array outside the function and pass it as parameter.
2. Use "return chars;" only;

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not okay to ignore that warning. The value you're returning is the address of `chars` on the stack, not the thing it points to. You want to return just `chars`.

Answer (score 0):

Others have given teh answer; but as a general observation I would recommend you look at the STL. You've tagged the question C and C++, so I'm assuming you're in a C++ environment and the STL is available.  You can then use typedefs to define vectors in a readable form , and even vectors of vectors (ie. 2d arrays). You can then return a pointer or reference (as appropriate) to your vector of vectors.